# change div content when parent page is different?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, frame

i want to change a div content when my page embed into another page
for exemple:

if the visitor access directly to the page:

```
<div id="msg"> this is my page </div>
```

if my page embed into a frame

```
<div id="msg"> my page into anthor page :)</div>
```

thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily check if page is in iframe using this trick:

```
var isInIFrame = (self != top);
```

So, you check it on page-loading and get something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isInIFrame = (self != top);
    if (isInIFrame)
        $("#msg").text("my page into anthor page :)");
});
```

And default value "this is my page" should be in markup file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with javascript (client side only). From this link;

http://billhiggins.us/blog/2009/04/09/detecting-that-youre-in-an-iframe/

You could do the following with javascript;

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
if(window !== top) {
   document.getElementById("msg").innerHtml("My page into another page")
}
</script>
```

Not tested, and from reading that article, issues to consider, but hopefully this gets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
if (window != top) {
    document.write('<div id="msg"> my page into anthor page :)</div>');
} else {
    document.write('<div id="msg"> this is my page </div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to accomplish this with JavaScript. You can detect whether your `window` object is the top-level browser window:

```
if (window === top){
  alert("I'm the top.");
} else {
  alert("I'm embedded.");
}
```